# Why is my datepicker not opening - BootstrapUI - Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get a `datepicker`  from `UI Bootstrap` to open when I click an icon.  Here is my `html`:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="opened"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
</p>
```

And here is my `js`:

```
scope.open = function() {
    scope.opened = true;
};

scope.opened = false;
```

When I click the button, I hit `open()`, `opened` is changed and nothing happens.  The `datepicker` does not appear.  The strange thing is, if I put the `ng-click` on the input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" ng-click="open()"/>
```

Then the `datepicker` works and opens like it should.  I am missing something somewhere.  Does anyone understand what the issue it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare the `opened` variable in an object.
2. Pass the $event object into the open event of your controller and call `$event.stopPropagation();` prior to setting `scope.status.opened = true`.

**Markup**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

**Controller**

```
scope.open = function ($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    scope.status.opened = true;
};
```

**Explanation As I Understand It.**

The `datepicker` directive generates html to render the datepicker popup. `stopPropagation()` prevents the javascript click event from cascading\bubbling out of the element that you clicked on.  The reason that you weren't seeing the popup is because the click event was bubbling down into that generated html, being handled a second time, and effectively closing the popup (similar behavior to opening the popup and then clicking again inside of the popup to close it).

Comment: Why would I need to `stopPropagation`?

Comment: Updated answer to provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue, as you are setting a model variable to a primitive.

Try declaring the `opened` variable in an object, e.g. `status.opened`:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

**Controller**

```
scope.status = {
    opened: false
}

scope.open = function () {
    scope.status.opened = true;
};
```

Comment: I tried that earlier.  It still doesn't open.  Again, I can put the exact code above on the `input` and it works fine.

Comment: I just logged the `status.opened` to my page and `status.opened` is not being updated in the `html`, so it is definitely some kind of `scope` issue.

Comment: Maybe a bugged version of ui-bootstrap? Could you reproduce the problem in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nVZIz7qTjkvLEro4prnR?p=preview)?